# Why do all Gods resemble humans and why are they mostly linked to Earth but not other planets where humans don't exist?

Tags: vishnu, vedas, shiva, bhagavata-purana

I have had this doubt right from my childhood.

Why do all Gods resemble humans and why are they mainly on Earth but not on other planets or other parts of the Universe where Humans don't exist?

For example, Lord Shiva is associated with Himalayas and Lord Vishnu with the Oceans and so on.

Does it mean Gods that we currently worship only belong to the Earth and there may be some other Gods for the rest of the Universe?

I am sorry if my question hurts anyone.

Comment: Yeah good question. God is everywhere. But we humans can relate better and understand easily if God appears like human and if God lives on Earth. Thus God comes and appears just we appear, and incarnates in places (although His residence is in Our Hearts) so that we can relate better. :)

Comment: Ganesha or Narsimha : two examples of god not resemble humans. Also, out of Vishnu's dash-avatar, few like Matsya, Varah do resemble non-humans, isn't it?

Comment: First of all it is not true that all gods resemble human shape. Hanuman resembles monkey, Vishnu has 4 arms and not 2 like humans, Narasimha has a lion head, Ananta Shesha is a huge snake, Kurma is a tortoise, Hayagriva is a equine, etc. They are all gods or divinities, or divine beings. Secondly, great gods live in the heaven world, and usually each of them has their own planet, eg Brahmaloka is planet of god Brahma, Indraloka is his own planet, etc.

Answer (score 1):

as my study i can say our gods r for full universe..see brahma is creator of whole universe...his story-a bubble which is egg arises from skin pore of karanodakshayi vishnu..that egg's story is same like chinese pangu that brahma is born outta it & all that becomes the universe..then 1st day brahma makes the creation then when his day ends & at next day he rises from garbhodakshayi vishnu's navel lotus...see like this innumerable & more bigger eggs appear from karanodakshayi vishnu's pores & in every of them is 1 brahma & a universe is 1/2 water which is garbhodak & 1/2 the space where planets etc. exists..so see why we don't talk on other worlds(within our universe)as what we really need is info about us...they don't wanna confuse us with other planet's life stuffs..in jainism u will see they talk on life beyond earth as their earth is of 2&1/2 dvipa & beyond that too innumerable divpa exist & they have given measurement of scorpion in the last sea where life exist...what i say is kailash & meru & ksheer sea of our earth r offices of gods for our earth department & there maybe more planets with their kailash meru ksheer sea etc. for their purpose as ours...as see vishnu r of 3 types..1)ksheerodakshayi who lives in ksheer sagar of earth..2)garbhodakshayi..the 1 who lies at down 1/2 half of universe supporting brahma & 3)karanodakshayi vishnu outta who's body all eggs comes & beyond that is krishna...see ISKCON for more on this..there r other worlds in our universe for sure but no info given of their human life there...as we say that brahma is lord of all universe so he is of all worlds existing in our universe...hope this helped..:)

Comment: You should cite sources.  And you should improve the formatting on your answer.

Comment: see for jainsim fact i told it is in book Tattvartha sutra...i can give u verse too for it...but this part was told by pulak sagar ji in his commentary on that book & that book's name is sarvagya vaani...so i can show u pic of that book if u need proof...but on net i don't think u will get that book...but i will try for it...& all hindu stuff is from iskcon's cosmology articles but those r many many so if u want i can tell an iskcon prabhuji to comment & tell my answer is authentic..sorry i m very weird guy so pls pardon

Answer (score 0):

God does not have any shape. He is infinite, nirakar. What we are seeing is symbolic only to exchange our view. When God take incarnation he can take any form not always human form . See matsya, Kachh, varah, nrusinham etc. God is for all the universe not only for earth. Earth may pass in the pore of the Infinite God means he is for entire universe. Kheersagar does not exist in the earth. It is somewhere else. We are talking about Gandharva & apsaras means they are from other world. Swarga & patal are the reference of other world. They are many world if they are connected with us then only we will talk about them otherwise not. Like the News channel of a country. we are getting the news only concern to us. There are almost two hundred country. we are not getting the news of all the country if it is not relevant to us. We are telling world cup with mere ten to twelve country in cricketing field where as in reality there are many country in the world. Similary in our vada the narration relevant to us only found. We talk about God ,relevant to us, who is the owner of n no of world but not talking about n no of world which is irrelevant to us .

Comment: God does have shape.